# Paulirish infinite scroll not working on my custom tumblr theme

Tags: jquery, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I'm making a custom tumblr theme, and I am trying to implement paul irish's infinite scroll plugin.

I really like the way the "simplist" theme by "precrafted" handles it (new posts triggered by a button). And If I understand correctly, it's easy to do.

I added the very newest paul irish minified script from github, the triggered script, and included the latest jquery version.

I set up my code like this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#content').infinitescroll({
            navSelector  : 'div.navigation',            
            nextSelector : 'div.navigation a:#next',    
            itemSelector : '#content div.entry',
            behavior     : 'twitter'
          },function(newElements){
            $(newElements).find('.photo-slideshow').pxuPhotoset();
        }
        });        
    </script>
```

(I am also using PXU extended photosets, which work, so I know that is not the problem)
and added my navigation div.

**It did nothing.**

Clicking on the next page actually moved me to the next page, instead of loading content dynamically.

Worse yet, normal infinite scroll didn't even work.

My Test tumblr is here: **http://test-theme-one.tumblr.com**

And my full html code is here: **http://pastebin.com/TRNR6V0U**

It's probably some stupid mistake I made, but perhaps someone could show me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in you JS:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

You'll need to change your code to look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#content').infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : 'div.navigation',            
    nextSelector : 'div.navigation a:#next',    
    itemSelector : '#content div.entry',
    behavior     : 'twitter'
},function(newElements){
    $(newElements).find('.photo-slideshow').pxuPhotoset();
});        
</script>
```

You'll notice the difference in the closing tags at the bottom of your infinite scroll function.

### Update

Your `nextSelector` is also incorrect. Right now you have `'div.navigation a:#next'` and it should be `'div.navigation a#next'` (note the removal of the colon).

Comment: Hmm, it didn't seem to change anything, clicking the next page still loaded the next page instead of adding the new content on.. It's odd because I followed the infscr documentation exactly (aside from changing the selector classes to match my own) and its like it just plain doesn't work.. Could It be that my version of query (1.10) is too new?

Comment: Clicking 'next' will always go to the next page. You'll want to hide those links if infinite scroll is enabled. You'll need to set up a click function to prevent default on that link and then trigger infinite scroll.

Comment: Ah I see, well I hid the class with css, and removed 'behavior: 'twitter' but It still doesn't load new content when I scroll to the bottom. Here is the updated html code (I took out all the useless stuff so it's just the important stuff) http://pastebin.com/bvNf6B67

Comment: Ah, I see they've updated the plugin to just use the nextSelector. In that case, I see the problem! Updated answer.

Comment: I did that, still no good. I can't think of what might be wrong, perhaps it's the placement of the navigation div, but that shouldn't matter, should it? As it stands, I can't even get the normal infinite scroll working

Comment: UPDATE: Problem solved. I am so dumb, I wrapped the script in a window.load function and it works like a charm! Thanks for all the help, I really really appreciate it!